# Глобальная переменная или класс?

Tags: python, классы

Конкретный пример. Есть функция create_order, которая создает ордер на бирже. Через некоторое время нужно убить ордера функцией cancel_order, которая в качестве аргумента будет принимать orderid. Дело в том, что функция create_order будется вызываться не один раз, а несколько, соотвественно orderid будет меняться для каждого последующего ордера. Я правильно понимаю, что здесь нужно создавать класс для решения задачи? С классами знаком поверхностно. Заранее благодарен за помощь!

```
def create_order(buyorsell, volume):
    rate = 0
    vol = 0
    balances = account()
    # available_usd = balances['return']['funds']['USD']['available']
    available_eur = balances['return']['funds']['EUR']['available']
    availabe_btc = balances['return']['funds']['BTC']['available']
    if (buyorsell == 'buy') and round((available_eur / get_bid_rate()), 1) <= volume:
        print('a')
        rate = get_bid_rate()
        vol = round((available_eur / rate), 1) - 1
    elif buyorsell == 'buy' and available_eur / get_bid_rate() > volume:
        print('b')
        rate = get_bid_rate()
        vol = volume
    elif buyorsell == 'sell' and available_eur > volume:
        print('c')
        rate = get_ask_rate()
        vol = volume
    elif buyorsell == 'sell' and available_eur <= volume:
        print('d')
        rate = get_ask_rate()
        vol = round(available_eur, 1) - 1


    pair = 'btceur'
    orderType = 'limit'
    params = {
    'type': buyorsell,
    'rate': rate,
    'volume': vol,
    'pair': pair,
    'orderType': orderType
        }

    order = request('/tapi/v2/order/new', params)
    orderid = order['return']['orderId']
    return orderid

def cancel_orders(orderid):
    request('/tapi/v2/order/cancel', {orderid})
    return
```

Comment: Неправильно. Не нужно. Но если хочется, то можно и создать, почему нет.

Comment: а какие есть другие варианты?

Comment: Другой вариант - не создавать класс. Поймите, классы - это не средство для решения задачи, это парадигма программирования.